# Autodesk Forge ../photo-to-3d/v1/file Error Code 14

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-realitycapture

Good Evening,

im geting the following error

```
   {
  "Usage": "0.55849504470825",
  "Resource": "/file",
  "Error": {
    "code": "14",
    "msg": "Specified values are invalid"
  }
}
```

im trying to post a survey file to to the photo scene - [following this documentation](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/reality-capture/v1/reference/http/file-POST/) the file i have given the extension type .gcp and formatted it as a xml as shown on the example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<surveydata coordinatesystem="LL84" description="Local coordinatesystem; meters" epsgcode="27700">
 <markers>
   <marker id="1" name="C2">
     <images>
       <image name="I100_0413_0027.jpg" xpixel="452" ypixel="401"/>
       <image name="I100_0413_0028.jpg" xpixel="454" ypixel="1105"/>
       <image name="I100_0413_0029.jpg" xpixel="464" ypixel="1840"/>
       <image name="I100_0413_0030.jpg" xpixel="455" ypixel="2564"/>
       </images>
     <gcp x="539840.423" y="263277.897" z="16.097" checkpoint="false"/>
   </marker>
   <marker id="2" name="C3">
     <images>
       <image name="I100_0413_0009.jpg" xpixel="1887" ypixel="488"/>
       <image name="I100_0413_0010.jpg" xpixel="1877" ypixel="1236"/>
       <image name="I100_0413_0011.jpg" xpixel="1868" ypixel="1958"/>
       <image name="I100_0413_0012.jpg" xpixel="1860" ypixel="2681"/>
       <image name="I100_0413_0013.jpg" xpixel="1850" ypixel="3400"/>
       </images>
     <gcp x="539783" y="263219.485" z="16.511" checkpoint="false"/>
   </marker>
      <marker id="3" name="C4">
     <images>
       <image name="I100_0413_0036.jpg" xpixel="4255" ypixel="348"/>
       <image name="I100_0413_0037.jpg" xpixel="4211" ypixel="1049"/>
       <image name="I100_0413_0038.jpg" xpixel="4167" ypixel="1758"/>
       <image name="I100_0413_0039.jpg" xpixel="4125" ypixel="2460"/>
        <image name="I100_0413_0040.jpg" xpixel="4063" ypixel="3168"/>
     </images>
     <gcp x="539845.368" y="263230.711" z="15.852" checkpoint="false"/>
   </marker>
 </markers>
</surveydata>
```

on the creation of the scene i have set `format=rcs`-`scenetype=aeria`l

this is the first time i have tried a survey file and i'm unsure what 'values' are invalid, could anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Survey File Example in [documentation](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/reality-capture/v1/reference/http/file-POST/), when you specify coordinate system as "LL84":

```
<surveydata coordinatesystem="LL84" ...
```

it expects in gcp the long, lat and alt:

```
<gcp long="38.014125" lat="-122.540530" alt="2010.200000" checkpoint="false"/>
```

In your case, you specify the gcp as x,y,z:

```
<gcp x="539840.423" y="263277.897" z="16.097" checkpoint="false"/>
```

Thus, try to change the coordinate system as "XYZ":

```
<surveydata coordinatesystem=“XYZ” ...
```

Although documentation states that "only LL84 is supported for now.", this should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the reply one more question i have changed my method to uploading them via a oss bucket, would it be the object key that goes in the place of the image name?
"bucketKey":  "denby-471471151",
"objectKey":  "image_0",
"objectId":  "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:denby-471471151/image_0",
 "sha1":  "8f33ad4eddc3612cf08a2127baf852f1409fafb8",
"size":  8397883,
"location":  "

Comment: @TD123123123 Reality Capture service has to access freely the input (and the output) files. Thus, if there is a need for authentication or authorisation, to access the files, it will fail. In context of OSS bucket, if you work with bucket keys and object keys, authentication is required (through a token) and consequently will fail. Consider using signed urls for that: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-signed-POST/

Comment: ok so in the xml file instead of the file name xyz.jpg it it would be the signed url for that image